# Ruby on Rails Expression in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I got little confused when I seen this code in a view file.

**<%= make_case_name payment, current_cart %>**

What does the above code do.. Where to look for this payment variable?

Comment: `payment` there can syntactically be a local variable, but given the context, it must be a method. There must be a method defined with that name in the model, controller, of helper.

Comment: @sawa: Unless a partial is a "view file" and `:locals => { :payment => ... }` was in the `render :partial => ...` call. Or if there's a `<% payment = 6 %>` elsewhere in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above code aims to call the method `make_case_name` with two arguments: `payment` and `current_cart`.

As this code is embedded in your view, that means `payment` and `current_cart` are local variable. The method `make_case_name` is located in your helper.

Anyway, if it's belongs to a specific project that you're working on, you should contact with the project owner or developers for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You have a following method which takes two parameters i.e payment and current_cart. Those are the local variables.

Structure is as follows

```
def make_case_name(payment, current_cart)
  # your logic code
end
```

As per my assumption your  **make_case_name** method may be present in the **helpers**.

**Note**: If you give few more details that would be helpful